# How to make AjaxCalender control in bigger size for Ipad website?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, calendar, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to make ajax Calander control in bigger size by overriding the style of default ajax Calender.

It should be work in larger view. I tried but its not working well when I tried to select month/year view..

Here I attached screenshot what exactly I want to do with ajax calender control.
[image]

Will it possible to make it larger view for iPad website?

OR Suggest me good calender control for Ipad website, I want to use asp.net website.

Thanks
abhishek

Answer (score -1):

i have just been through this myself. there are a 3 things you need to do.

**First** - add a css class to your control. But beware if you do this it wipes the existing class of ajax__calendar and so most of its existing styling so add to the CalendarExtender

```
 CssClass="ajax__calendar bigcal"
```

where bigcal is your new class.

**Second** - add your css for the styling using the bigcal class - e.g.

```
.bigcal .ajax__calendar_container { width: 220px; font-size:14px;}
.bigcal .ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_container {border: 3px solid #646464;}
.bigcal .ajax__calendar_days, .bigcal .ajax__calendar_months, .bigcal .ajax__calendar_years, .bigcal .ajax__calendar_body
{width:220px;height:200px}
.bigcal .ajax__calendar_month, .bigcal .ajax__calendar_year{height:55px;padding-top:4px}
.bigcal .ajax__calendar_container table, .bigcal .ajax__calendar_container TD {font-size:14px}
.bigcal .ajax__calendar_days td div{padding:4px 5px 4px 4px}
```

Notice i have reset the size of it to 220 wide and 200 high - adjust accordingly

**Third** - you need to change the size of it in the javascript, cos it defaults to a set size for the scrolling etc to work. so

Add the following to the CalendarExtender

```
OnClientShown="setBigCal"
```

and then the following js function

```
function setBigCal(sender, e) {
    sender._height = 200;
    sender._width = 220;
}
```

HTH  :)

EDIT - Sorry - just seen the date on this question so i assume you are already sorted. But I will leave the answer up incase anyone else gets the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

i know my answer is late. i know you are asking about ajax calender. but it may help others. several programmers ask how to format asp.net calender. You can format asp.net calendar using following styles:

```
.calander {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 305px;
    width: 280px;
}

    .calander table tr td {
        padding: 10px;
    }

        .calander table tr td:hover {
            background-color:rgb(200, 255, 0);
        }

.ajax__calendar_today {
    background-color: rgb(209, 233, 255) !important;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.ajax__calendar_footer {
    background-color: rgb(209, 233, 255) !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    position: relative !important;
    height: auto !important;
}

.ajax__calendar_active {
    background-color: rgb(200, 255, 0) !important;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.ajax__calendar_day {
    height: 20px !important;
    width: 20px !important;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}

.ajax__calendar_body {
    width: 270px !important;
    height: 245px !important;
}

.ajax__calendar_container {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

these styles can be customized any way you want.